# Add REST Webservice to current MVC web application

Tags: php, rest, web-services, model-view-controller

I have a MVC based PHP application using a Front Controller to load the proper Controller depending on the request parameters. The application is working fine with multiple Controllers and  Views and now I want to expand it in order to handle REST requests from mobile clients (answering in JSON).

I am not sure about the most suitable architecture for the described scenario. Some people recommend creating different Controllers for REST type requests. The Front Controller would be the one in charge of loading the proper rest controllers or the controllers of the web application. The views would be different (the views for REST request would build a JSON response).

Other option is without building new controllers for REST calls and just adding new logic to the ones I'm using right now. I could create the view passing an extra argument, indicating if it has to be a JSON response or HTML response and the View could build the output depending on this parameter.

What do you think would be the best solution for adding REST Webservices to a current PHP-MVC app?

Comment: Ideally if web and app are going to use the same RESTful methods then your web should also use API's to communicate and get the data. Hope it made sense

Comment: Thank you Dhaval. The web is going to do more user of the controllers as they also handle navigation logic (which is not requiered by REST consumers). For example, links wich contain some get parameters.

Comment: so what i basically meant is database related activities should happen via API's only and no direct Model calls from the controller

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem. When I need to update something in my database and show other view (not JSON) to the user, where do I handle the creation of a different output?

Comment: Other example: sometimes the controller apart from updating the model, also gets some data from it in order to build the view (this would not be necessary in case it is a rest call)

Comment: you will get the data in JSON and like Androind and IOS developers would do, you also need to decode that data (json_decode()) and then work with it. That is the best way to creating a system that no platform should be able to fetch and push data directly into the database.everything happens via same API.

Comment: The thing is not the case. We are talking about a web app that is rendered on server side and has working controllers which are on charge of using the model for the business logic and data. The views are not loading data via AJAX calls, they are built with the data passed from the controller. The rest calls will only get/post/put/delete some data, so it's a different use case.